# Using Makefile with subfolders

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following directory structure.

```
Project/
    ├── bin/
    ├── src/
    │    ├── main.c
    │    ├── util/
    │         ├── util.c
    │         ├── util.h
    ├── obj/
    ├── .depend/
```

All my source code are in the src folder. In the src root is my main.c file; which includes other files that are on the same level that he (or within a same level folder). I have a Makefile below that works well for all files in the same level of main.c but does not work on files in a subfolder within src

**How change my Makefile to allow subfolder within the src folder?**

```
CC := gcc
CFLAGS := -Wall -Wextra
BINDIR := bin
OBJDIR := obj
SRCDIR := src
DEPDIR := .depend
SOURCES := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c)
OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.c, $(OBJDIR)/%.o, $(SOURCES))
DEPENDS := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.c, $(DEPDIR)/%.d, $(SOURCES))

$(BINDIR)/app: $(OBJECTS) | $(BINDIR)
    @$(CC) -o $@ $^

-include $(DEPENDS)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c | $(OBJDIR)
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

$(DEPDIR)/%.d: $(SRCDIR)/%.c | $(DEPDIR)
    @$(CC) -MM -MG $< | sed 's!^\(.\+\).o:!$(DEPDIR)/\1.d $(OBJDIR)/\1.o:!' > $@

$(DEPDIR) $(BINDIR) $(OBJDIR):
    @mkdir $@

clean:
    @rm -rf $(BINDIR)/*
    @rm -rf $(OBJDIR)/*

.PHONY: clean
```

**EDIT**: the `.o` and `.d` files do not need to respect the original design of the structure. And I'm using Windows (MinGW)

Comment: You need to specify more details. Such as where do you expect to create the `.o` and `.d` files for source files in subdirectories: whether all of them get also created in the same flat directory, or in the equivalent subdirectory. You also need to specify your platform as well, since there may be platform-specific tools that can be used.

Comment: Sorry, the .o and .d files do not need to respect the original design of the structure. And I'm using Windows (MinGW)

Comment: You need to generate an isomorphic directory structure for object files. It is  possible using pure make, but the initial boilerplate code is a bit long-winded. I am thinking of creating a github repo for that.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin, check out this: https://github.com/igagis/prorab

Comment: @igagis Interesting. One makefile per target is a bit inconvenient though.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin it is possible to declare many targets in a single makefile, there is a "clear-this-vars" function which resets all this_* variables, so after that it is possible to start over declaration for the next target.

Answer (score 3):

First, you'll have to change your `SOURCES` to recursively find the sources. This can be done in pure make:

```
subdirs = $(filter-out $1,$(sort $(dir $(wildcard $1*/))))
rfind = $(wildcard $1$2) $(foreach d,$(call subdirs,$1),$(call rfind,$d,$2))

SOURCES := $(call rfind,$(SRCDIR)/,*.c)
```

Everything else will work, except for directory creation. First, change your prerequisites to use `$(@D)` with secondary expansion:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c | $$(@D)
    ...
$(DEPDIR)/%.d: $(SRCDIR)/%.c | $$(@D)
    ...
```

Then, change your directory creation rule to include all the directories:

```
$(BINDIR) $(patsubst %/,%,$(sort $(dir $(OBJECTS) $(DEPENDS)))):
    @mkdir -p $@
```

Like the recursive find, it uses `sort` to deduplicate the directories (otherwise make will warn) and strips the trailing slash (because `$(@D)` won't have a trailing slash). Note that `-p` is needed to avoid issues with order and with directories only containing other directories and no sources.

Answer (score 0):

try to set your sources like this:

`SOURCES := $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -type f -name "*.c")`

if it does not work right a way, try to debug it by just running in your command line

`find src -type f -name "*.c"`

and see if it outputs the correct list of files and with correct relative path, adjust accordingly.

Note, that this approach works only in unix-like environment, if you are using MinGW from MSYS or Cygwin environment it should work.